# put a rails collection into asset templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, ruby-on-rails-3.1, backbone.js, assets

I have a backbone.js front-end and Rails backend, and all my template files are in the `assets` directory.

I want to implement a select list in one of my templates, with the data coming from a controller.

For example, I have an `AccountController` and I want the user to be able to select from available accounts. Right now, I've got an AJAX request to build the accounts select list, but that isn't efficient.

Is there a way to inject my Rails data into my templates before the templates are sent to the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are OK with using [mustache.js](http://mustache.github.com/) to render your templates, [poirot](https://github.com/olivernn/poirot) can do exactly what you're trying to do.  With [this](https://github.com/olivernn/poirot) you can have rails data rendered into the template before rendering the template on the front-end, and you can also use the same mustache template for both back-end and front-end.  Keep it DRY yo.

Another way to solve the problem would be to name your JS files like so:  example.js.erb, which allow you to render the select HTML or data directly to the JS file, and use it as needed.

Comment: thanks Scott, I apologize that it took me so long to get back to this, and I haven't had a chance to try poirot yet, but I think it is exactly what I'm looking for. The other way doesn't work as well because I want to have access to the controller.